# Strange result with mutate in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to replace "Unknown" values for a variable in a data frame by using the mutate function, but I got a very strange result and couldn't figure out why.

Below are the codes I ran. I was expecting "-unknown-" being replaced "TBD" in "gender2" while other things remain the same as "gender". However, in "gender2", "FEMALE" was changed to "2", "MALE" was changed to "3" and "OTHER" was changed to "4" unexpectedly. Anyone can point out the root causes? Thank you very much!

```
> summary(Train$gender)
-unknown-    FEMALE      MALE     OTHER 
    94961     62023     53685       279 

> Train <- Train %>% mutate(gender2 = factor(ifelse(gender != "-unknown-", gender, "TBD")))

> summary(Train$gender2)
    2     3     4   TBD 
62023 53685   279 94961
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the column is already a `factor`.  So, when we use `ifelse`, it gets coerced to integer storage values.

```
v1 <- factor(c('A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'))
ifelse(v1 != 'A', v1, "TBD") 
#[1] "TBD" "2"   "TBD" "2"   "3"
```

checking the integer coersion values

```
as.integer(v1)
#[1] 1 2 1 2 3
```

Instead, it can be

```
ifelse(v1 != 'A', as.character(v1), "TBD")
#[1] "TBD" "B"   "TBD" "B"   "C"
```

---

So, we can change the column to `character` and then wrap with `factor`

```
library(dplyr)
Train <- Train %>% 
            mutate(gender2 = factor(ifelse(gender != "-unknown-", 
                  as.character(gender), "TBD")))
```

---

Or instead of doing the convert/reconvert, use `fct_recode`

```
library(forcats)
Train <- Train %>%
             mutate(gender2 = fct_recode(gender, "TBD" = "-unknown-"))
```

---

Using a reproducible example

```
iris1 <- iris %>%
            mutate(Species2 = fct_recode(Species, "TBD" = "setosa"))
summary(iris1$Species2)
#   TBD versicolor  virginica 
#    50         50         50
```

Just wanted to mention that `summary` works on `factor` column in getting the frequency count.  We can use `table` as well that is more general as it can work on different `type`s

```
table(iris1$Species2)
table(as.character(iris1$Species2))
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation! One follow up question:  can I use ifelse function together with fct_recode? My ultimate goal is to replace "unknow" to either "FEMALE" or "MALE" under conditions. Thank you!

Comment: @ClaireSun if you have some logical conditions, use the `ifelse` with your method as the logic is not very clear

Comment: @rnorouzian looks like lot of answers

Comment: @rnorouzian Sorry, was offline.  I hope the answers there work for you